# delay deep link navigation with react navigaton

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Any time I click on a deep link for my app it goes directly to that screen and the app crashes because the data has not fully loaded for that screen yet

I have tried to delay the Navigation Action that takes place until after my data has loaded but nothing has worked.

Expected Example:
User clicks on deep link `myapp://home/profile/Tom`
App wakes up, handles logic (i.e. is user logged in/allowed access to this screen)
App navigates to this page or not depending on app data

Actual Experience:
User clicks on deep link
App navigates directly to screen
Crashes because data hasn't come back from the server yet

**Note:**
The app works as expected if the app was already started but this issue persists if the user taps on a deep link and the app was closed

Comment: Do you use `redux`?

Comment: no not using redux @anhtu

Comment: I think the best ux is let the app navigate, then show loading and fetching api. Or your put the navigating code to the `then()` part of api

Comment: What do you mean by the `then()` part of the api? Could you write a code snippet example?

Comment: I mean: user click on deep link -> show loading -> fetch api -> then you got data -> navigate

Comment: You are misunderstanding, the issue is that the app seems to automatically navigate to a deeplink destination on clicking. React-navigation doesnt allow the app to delay the navigation. Unless I am using react-navigation incorrectly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont think react-navigation can handle `myapp://home/profile/Tom` automatically.

Comment: I think you should move code `Linking.getInitialURL()` place after StackNavigator created.

Comment: were you able to fix this? i'm facing the same issue